What do four dots under/over a whole note mean?
I'm working on transcribing a piece and I ran across a series of whole notes (no tremolo or subdivision slashes) with four dots over/under them depending on how high/low they were on the staff. I reckon this means to divide each whole note into quarter notes, but does this also mean each note should be played staccato? Or is the articulation ambiguous in this case?


Please add the title, composer, measure numbers, and instrument. All could impact the answer and will help anyone with this question in the future.

This seems a perfect  example, where NOT to use abbreviated notation. Even expanding one bar with subsequent percent repetition markers would be better.

Those aren't whole notes, they're stemless half notes. Whatever that means.

According to a similar question answered here, the dots indicate that underlying quarter notes should be played staccato.

This doesn’t explain why there aren’t any tremolo beams.

@ElementsInSpace But if the division is quarter notes, what would the beams represent? A single beam is eighth notes, double beam is sixteenth notes, etc.

@Aaron That’s a good point. I think those minim-shaped whole note noteheads threw me off.

I suppose this would be a part for a wind instrument. Multiple dots under a single note is used in wind instruments for the sake of multiple tonguing — usually that would be double tongue. So instead of articulating single notes you use different tongue movements to articulate more notes in one motion.

Why four dots, then? There's double and triple tonguing, but not quad. Plus, how would double-tonguing, say, apply to whole notes?

@Aaron I suppose it implies two double tongues. It applies to whole notes the same as to any other note, although it requires a certain tempo to make sense. Of course it is hard to say with the small excerpt given by the OP. But if it is a part for wind instrument this would be my interpretation.
